# Rewrite the field label text on node dispaly

Tags: 7, entities

I created a content type. 
In the content type I have field called ingredients. Machine name is "field_ingredients".

When a user see the output of the node (not in form and not in views), the label is:
"ingredients:".
I want the remove the ":" or even change the label to something else.

How can I do that?

I tried the "preprocess_node" function, but it didn't succeed.

Comment: What is the type of the 'ingredients' field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override [field.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7) to do this (the colon is hard coded into that template file).

Create field.tpl.php anywhere in your theme folder, copy the code from the above link into it, tweak it (remove the colon etc), then clear your caches: all will be well!

I found Answer from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491255/how-do-i-remove-a-colon-from-a-label)